# rmarkdown html embed pdf/eps

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to make an R markdown HTML document in Rstudio. I have a number of images that I have in pdf and eps format. I'm trying to embed these into the output with the `\includegraphics{path to image}` command. However, the output HTML doesn't show anything.

Comment: `\includegraphics` is a LaTeX command and won't be recognized by HTML.  I've never tried placing a pdf or eps in an HTML document, but my first attempt would be to use `![alt text](figures/img.png)`, the markdown syntax for including images. (but I have no idea if it will work)

Comment: No (sane) browser is going to render PDF or EPS files as base64 encoded inline images (which is the default behaviour of knitting). They won't as `<img src=../>` / `![](…)` either. You'll have more luck converting them to SVG and doing what @Benjamin suggested.

Comment: Might probably need to `shiny::HTML()` to embed off file into shiny app in rmarkdown HTML webpage...

Answer (score 2):

R-markdown is also a markdown. Markdown itself doesn't have a mechanism for embedding a PDF, however, Markdown [accepts raw HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) in its input and passes it through unaltered.

There are many ways to do this, one of the recommended ways is-

```html
<object data="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="700px" height="700px">
    <embed src="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf">
        <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
    </embed>
</object>
```