# How can I insert pdf images in an R presentation?

Tags: r, image, pdf, markdown, r-markdown

I am writing an R presentation in an .Rpres file. I published my presentation on Rpubs here: http://rpubs.com/cr517/presentationGurdon
I have images stored in PDF files. I am trying to include them in my presentation, unsuccesfully. I am using this command to include the images:

```
![Chromosome sizes](input/images/bar/nbOfGenesPerChrom.pdf)
```

the same as for .jpg. This command does not result in the display of the image. I have tried to follow these answers but could not make it work:

[R markdown: can I insert a pdf to the r markdown file as an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173714/r-markdown-can-i-insert-a-pdf-to-the-r-markdown-file-as-an-image)

[Add pdf file in Rmarkdown file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073041/add-pdf-file-in-rmarkdown-file)

If somebody could help me, that would be much appreciated. That would spare me the re-run of my code exporting images in .jpg format.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592984/rmarkdown-html-embed-pdf-eps